# Objective-C Degree of pin in regard to user's location

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to calculate at what degree a pin is to the user's location. So if the pin is directly below the user's location, it would be 180 degrees. Directly to the right would be 90. There could be one between those at 154 degrees. 0 degrees is 0 degrees north of the user's location. Directly south is 180 degrees.

I've been having trouble calculating this and I wanted to know if this is even possible? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is possible, what have you tried. You can simplify into a trigonometry problem with assumptions / caveats...

Comment: Certainly it's possible. Basically you are asking: given two coordinates, what is the compass bearing from one to the other? Of course it's a bit tricky because the world is round, but obviously it can be done or one wouldn't be able to find one's way out of the woods. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have two points, both consisting of Latitude and Longitude, or X, Y.  Assuming the user is facing north, this could be done as follows:

```
//Make sure you import math.h

CGPoint currentLocation = CGPointMake(100.2, 55.53);
CGPoint pin = CGPointMake(125.54, 40.23);

//Shift the 2D space to have the currentLocation as the origin
pin.x -= currentLocation.x;
pin.y -= currentLocation.y;

//Calculate the inverse tangent (in radians)
float rad = atan(pin.y/pin.x);

//Convert the radians to degrees
float deg = rad * 180/M_PI;
```